# to manipulate input variable in the set of arguments of R function

Tags: r, arguments

I am trying to solve the issue of input variable manipulation in R function. The function is as follows:

```
testFun<-function(x,y){
   x+y
}
```

I  want to run in such a way:

```
testFun(x=1,y=5+x)
```

but the error is generated:

> Browse[1]> testFun(x=1,y=5+x)
>   Error during wrapup: object 'x' not found

From the argument evaluation poin of view it is a mistake. So I need to have 'x' either a default value or outside value (details I have scanned in http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-arguments).

So **my question** is whether it is possible to make such a manipulation in one row, without making a wrappers or outside values?

It is supposed to have the output:

run:

> testFun(x=1,y=5+x)

output:

> 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<-` but it will create the variable in your global environment. See the following for example:

```
testFun(x <- 1, y = 5 + x)
# [1] 7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) You have shown a very nice and short example.
I will experiment with such an approach now.